# Mesh looking broken in perspective camera but okay in ortographic

Tags: mesh, camera, sculpting

I'm newbie, and I've been searching everywhere in YT and forums and I found no one with similar issues with me.

disclaimer I'm not so sure what's the issues here, the mesh/vertex or just the cam settings

**Here's the pic.**
In orthographic camera:
[image: Model and mesh looking fine in orthographic cam]

In perspective camera:

[image: Model and mesh looking broken in perspective cam]

---

**More info about the model:**

I worked on viewport with 100mm focal length

The model is very high density. I remeshed until (?) voxel.

I know I should retopo but nope, ain't doing it for this project.

I noticed the broken meshes (or is it the vertex?) are the model for the clothes ONLY, except the top outer shirt

body/skin is unaffected; shoes, hair, eyeball is unaffected.

**How I work on the model:**

I made those skin tight clothes by using this technique: Mask select and extract. And then I solidify the thickness into negative (-0.01m) because I like the presentation better than the positive number.

I did not remesh or meddle with normals or mesh or merge vertex by distance, or any other mesh/vertex option or tools.

---

**What I tried to do** (ofc nothing work):

(feel free to retest bcs I might do someting wrong)

- Flipping the normals
- Solidifying to positive numbers
- Hiding the body (thinking that the mesh is overlapping with the clothes mesh)
- Changing the render camera focal length:
  it's kinda working but not really what I wanted bcs it zoomed in too much
- Messing with Cameras clip end setting

---

**Hypothesis**

I think it perspective camera will work with certain camera settings but idk where to start. I don't even know what is my situation called so I can't really search for this specific problem.

Also is this problem happened because my model is problematic? Or is it just simple camera setting issue? I need to know if I should change my sculpting method. How do I avoid this in the future?

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H6I-Va6UwW1he9DVvhnWNe62coEeSayN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You really expect anyone to download a Blend file that's over 1Gb in size? That's a ridiculous size for just a simple model anyway.

Comment: Nope I don't. That's why I'm putting every details I could.